# Android - Listview pauses for a moment although no new inflation is done

Tags: android, android-listview, android-view

I have a `Listview` with custom rows. There are ~15 rows.
Every time a row has been inflated, I save them to a `Hashmap` so that I don't have to inflate it again. I have a limited number of rows, so I think I can save all rows in the map. Next time the same row is asked for, I just pull the view out of the `Hashmap` and return it.

So, first time during scrolling to the bottom it stutters, which is understandable.
But the problem is that even after all views has been put into the Hashmap, If i do a fast swipe to scroll from all the way from top to bottom(or bottom to top) it scrolls to almost 80% distance smoothly and then "PAUSES" for a moment and then continues the scrolling and finally settles down at the end. the remaining 20% also scrolls smoothly(But after the PAUSE).

I put logs in the `public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)` function and made sure that no inflation is happening ever again after the initial scrolling to the bottom.

I also tried
`mListView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
mListView.setScrollingCacheEnabled(false);`

but its of no use. I can still see the pause.
Can anybody help me to fix this issue?

Thanks,
Androbean.

Comment: Why would you go to such length? It makes no sense.

The Listview basically does what you're trying to do. It inflates enough views to fill the screen, and then reuses old views when scrolling, so it doesn't have to inflate more views than the screen can show.

Comment: @Kasper I understand your point. The reason I am doing so is because each row in my case has a HorizontalScrollview with a variable number of items. Also loading these items is heavy, so re-using rows didn't feel like a good idea in this specific case.

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to solve the issue.
The real problem however has no direct correlation with the behavior I was seeing.

I am loading images from PackageManager like this.
`Drawable drawable = packageManager.getDrawable(info.provider.getPackageName(), info.previewImage, null)`;

It seems depending on device density some auto scaling has been happening and I was getting some unreasonably large images. Once I started scaling them down and started using the properly sized images, the problem vanished. !

I still wonder why scrolling was smooth up to 80% then PAUSE & then smooth again for next 20%.